# Register validation query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to make a register validation . When i verify if the "Name" and "Email" belong (or not) to other user i want the query for this operation to return the values that doesn't fit to my requirements . For example if the "Email" introduced by the user isn't found in the database but the "Name" already belongs to a user , the query should return "Name" , if both the name and the email belongs to other user, the query will return "Name,Email" (or something similar) .I know i can do 2 separated select queries for the name and email and check their outputs , but the procedure is kind of exhausting .

Here is a piece of 'code' (not really compilable code but hopefully clear enough) , but i have no idea how to implement it in sql .
.

```
x = "nameExample"//user input 
y = "emailExample" //user input
output = ''
for each user in Users      
    if user.Name == x or user.Email == y
       if user.Name == x 
          output.concatenate("Name");
         
       if user.Email == y 
          output.concatenate("Email");
```

Comment: This would be a very basic SQL query. You can start from the [MySQL tutorial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/entering-queries.html) or [another quick SQL training](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp). Update your question with your own attempts if you still have troubles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like below,

```
SELECT concat(
       case when name is not null 
            then name else '' 
       end,
       case when email is not null 
             and name is not null 
            then concat(',',email) 
            when email is not null 
            then email 
            else '' 
       end) name_and_email
FROM name_email
```

link to [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=58482a5fe40af39ed08df9b48452610d)